# Error in save method Hibernate with relation ManyToOne

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i'm trying save a class Equipment, howhever when i'm using save method in Service, i'm having an error:

*" ERROR 14620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "name_model" of relation "equipment_model" does not exist "*

more specifically, the problem is in SQL command: 'Hibernate: insert into operation.equipment_model (name, id) values (?, ?)'

Having this problem, I have a doubt, to create a new Equipment, I really need create a EquipmentModel too? Because in my SQL "EquipmentModel" have only 2 rows: id, name.

**EQUIPMENT**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="equipment")
public class Equipment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Equipment(){
        equipmentModel = new EquipmentModel();
        this.equipment_model_id = equipmentModel.getId();
    }
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name="equipment_model_id")
private UUID equipment_model_id;


@NotNull
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
private EquipmentModel equipmentModel;

//Getters and Setters }
```

**EQUIPMENT MODEL**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="equipment_model")
public class EquipmentModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String nameModel;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipmentModel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Equipment> equipments;

      // Getters Setters }
```

**EQUIPMENT SERVICE:**

```
@Service
 public class EquipmentService { final EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;
public EquipmentService(EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository)
{
    this.equipmentRepository = equipmentRepository;
}


@Transactional
public Equipment save(Equipment equipment)
{ return equipmentRepository.save(equipment);    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of your annotations:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EquipmentModel equipmentModel;
```

`cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is getting all actions from one entity to another. That means deletes, persists (what you are trying) and many more.

You might want to change your annotation to

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private EquipmentModel equipmentModel;
```

This means, that there are no cascade types, because the default value is an empty array. That means it will not try to save anything from your `EquipmentModel` while also trying to save your `Equipment`.

Comment: Ahhh... thank you! A simple annotation ruining my code, I'll read more about cascades thanks bro